# How to send local notifications even when app is closed

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms

How can I schedule a background task in my xamarin forms app to run, even if the app is closed. The background task has to check something every hour into a database. Based on the result from database I need to send a notification to the user, for instance the message notifications like in whatsapp.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, You can do this. When your app is minimised that time you set schedule 1 hour for local notification. You nee to do platform specific code

Comment: With What plugin? if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule local notification by using [LocalNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin).

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body", 101, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
```

In case that you want to implement periodical background thread you need to write platform specific code. Follow this article [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/).